# How disable local googlemap zoom which appears on android tablet

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, zooming

[image: effet zoom partiel sur tablette Samsung android]
Hello,
I would like to disable the local zoom of google map on tablet android.
I use the click for another use, also i don't want to see this partiel zoom.(you can see photo of my android tablet)
I have no problem with my PC or my iPhone anywhere.
what can I do ?
Thanks a lot.
Trachy

Here is the configuartion of the map:

```
var centreCarte = new google.maps.LatLng(latcentrecarto, longcentrecarto);
    var optionsCarte = {
           zoom: zoominitialcarto,
           center: centreCarte,
zoomControl: false,
mapTypeControl: true,
scaleControl: false,
streetViewControl: false,
rotateControl: false,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
 disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
clickableIcons:false,
streetViewControl:false,
draggable:false,
  };
      mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), optionsCarte);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem concern the "one finger zoom".

But in fact, I don't realise application specially for Android, I use googlemap Api http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

Also I can't use mymap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false); because this function is not in the API.

I don't really understand why "the one finger zoom" can be active on the map, because I don't load GV3 API Android.

An idea to solve the problem ? Thanks Trachy

Answer (score 0):

The function `mymap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false)` will not work in your code because this function is for [Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls#zoom_gestures) not in javaScript.

Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls) of Google Maps JavaScript API that shows the different controls.

For more information, check this related SO question:

- [Toggling zooming and panning ability on Google Maps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496158/toggling-zooming-and-panning-ability-on-google-maps)
- [Disabling pinch-zoom on google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059041/disabling-pinch-zoom-on-google-maps-desktop)

Comment: Yes but how gesture can be interpreted by my application if i do'nt use Android API ?